# Make ids query using SolrIndexSearcher

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I want to do ids query to SolrIndexSearcher (fetch several documents from solr using their ids) - something like ids query to SolrServer q=*:*&ids=ID1,ID2&fl=* .

I tried to call search(Query,int) in several ways with no success

i.e.

```
TopDocs results = this.indexSearcher.search(QueryParsing.parseQuery("q=\\*\\:\\*&ids=ID1,ID2&fl=*", this.indexSearcher.getSchema()) , MAX_DOCUMENTS);
```

results is allways empty..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search as `q=ids:(ID1 OR ID2)` which will search for the ids.
You can also use filter query `q=*:*&fq=ids:(ID1 OR ID2)` which is a performant approach as it utilizes the Filter cache.

Comment: you can not use ids in fq, it returns "undefined field ids" error

Comment: Who said so !!!!!! Ids can be used anywhere Filter, Sort, Range Search. Check if you have defined a field with Id. This answer is generic check your settings before you down vote an answer which has worked and accepted !!!

Comment: it is not working on Solr 5x, with cloud, returning the error messssage i mentioned, however, if you put ids to the url as a normal parameterm, you can retrieve only those ids from the index... you can check solr/lucene mailing list for further information, as well as my own mails to see details, fq with ids definitely not working

Comment: undefined field ids -> Clearly states there is not field with the name ids. Its a generic field and should work as this is a basic functionality. And surely the answer does not take into account for Future versions !!